# Send HTML form through PHP mail() function

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail

I need help with sending form using mail() function. I'm really beginner in all this! I've made a web site from a template and I can't make the contact form sent... I tried reading posts of other members but my php script return Nothing at all! blank page...

here I leave my HTML form and the php script :

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="enviar.php" enctype="text/plain">

                        <label for="author">Nombre:</label> <input type="text" id="author" name="author" class="required input_field" />
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

                        <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

                        <label for="subject">Sujeto:</label> <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input_field" />
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

                        <label for="text">Mensaje:</label> <textarea id="texto" name="texto" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

                        <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" />
                        <input type="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" name="reset" id="reset" value="Borrar" />
```

And here is the PHP script!! I actually tried many of them :(

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['contact'])) {

//configuration
$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Contacto desde zappingshow.tv";

// Validate data
if(!isset($_POST['author']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['subject']) ||
!isset($_POST['texto'])) {

echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
echo "<a href="inicio.html">Volver a la página de inicio</a>";
die();
}

$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['author'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Correo: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Asunto: " . $_POST['subject'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['texto'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message);

echo "¡El formulario se ha enviado con éxito!";
}
?>
```

The matter is I'm using a local server,, Uniserver Zero XI (I can't install easyphp in my computer don't know why)

I'm very beginner in all this! is probably that you find it a little sutpid ! but I would really appreciate your help

Thank you ^^

Comment: Just a heads up, it may work live but not local - depends on your localhost setup.

Comment: Also, this will break your string `"<a href="inicio.html">`. Either use singlequotes as appropriate (i.e., `'<a href="inicio.html">'`) or escape your in-string doubles with backslash `"<a href=\"inicio.html\">`

Answer (score 1):

`enctype="text/plain"` tells the browser to encode the data in a format that is for debugging purposes and is not machine readable. When you do that, PHP will not populate `$_POST`. Remove that attribute.